# null and undefined inconsistent comparison

Tags: javascript, operators, equality-operator

I'm curious to know why

```
null == undefined
```

returns `true` but

```
null >= undefined
```

returns `false`

Is the inclusion of the greater than operator coercing the values differently?

Comment: `undefined` is a variable, that happens to be *undefined* as long you don't define it

Comment: I think coercion only works with "==". Edit: hmm interesting, false >= null actually returns true. So now I am curious as well ;)

Comment: `Is the inclusion of the greater than operator coercing the values differently?` The inclusion of `>` means the values DON'T get coerced.

Comment: Sorry, what does 'coerced' mean in this context?

Comment: Why would false >= null return true if >= does not coerce?

Comment: @rism but why does false >= null return "true" then?

Comment: Because something is greater than nothing.

Comment: its not about greater, "greater" will not work. It only works bc its ">="

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr** The `>=` ends up coercing both arguments to numbers in this case: `undefined` gets coerced to `NaN` while `null` gets coerced to `0`, which aren't equal. For `==`, the spec explicitly defines that `null == undefined` is `true`.

---

The values do, in fact, get coerced in both cases (in a sense, at least - the case with `==` is special). Let's consider them one at a time, with the help of the spec.

The [algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.4) for the `>=` operator uses the ["Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm"](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5), which is shared by other relational operators. From the description in the spec, we see that the algorithm does the following:

1. Converts the arguments to primitives (which `null` and `undefined` already are).
2. Checks if the arguments are `String`s (which they are not).
3. If they are not `String`s, the algorithm **converts the arguments to numbers (see steps 3.a. and 3.b.)** and performs the comparison with the results.

The last point is the key. From the [`ToNumber` table](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3), we see that `undefined` gets coerced to `NaN`, and the algorithm considers any comparison with `NaN` as being falsy (see steps 3.c. and 3.d.). Thus, `null >= undefined` is `false`.

---

For the other case, `==`, the story is actually much simpler: the [spec explicitly states](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) that `null == undefined` is true as part of the "Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm" (see steps 2. and 3.). Thus, `null == undefined` is `true`.

Comment: Good explanation. So this also explains why false >= null results in "true", bc both values would be coerced to "0" then, correct?

Comment: @docta_faustus: Exactly.

Comment: @frontend_dev: Yep, both `false` and `null` get coerced to `+0`.

Comment: `The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm` Wow that's a gob full. Learnt something though, so nice one.

Comment: alert(+null) // 0
alert(+undefined) // NaN

Answer (score 0):

In JS `==` operator coerces values to same type to compare, so `1=="1"` is `true`. Use `===` operator for exact type matching

Comment: Not really asking about the difference between == and == but rather the difference between == and >=