# Why does null > -1 return true in js?

Tags: javascript, null, compare, undefined

Why does the below condition return false

```
   console.log(undefined > -1)
```

but, the below code returns true

```
    console.log(null > -1)
```

Does that mean null has an actual value rather than undefined? Also,

```
    console.log(undefined > 0)
```

Does that mean null has a value between 0 and -1?

Comment: It's due to type coercion. `undefined` is getting converted to a number becoming `NaN`. `NaN > -1 // false`, but `null` becomes `0` which is greater than `-1` --- Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34055818/null-and-undefined-inconsistent-comparison

Comment: Although it's not exactly as I say becuase `null == 0 // false`